# Py2exe/Python26/ArcGIS10 producing no executable file

Tags: python, arcgis

I am running ArcGIS 10, Python2.6 and the appropriate py2exe version on my computer (32bit system, Windows XP). I have been trying to package up a python script into a windows executable file. My setup.py runs without any errors, but produces no output.I use wxpython in my script and also made sure that the MSVCP90.DLL is in my referenced directory , but still no luck.

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest", glob(r'C:\test\viscruntime\*.*'))]
setup(data_files=data_files, windows=["test.py"])
```

I should mention that this has worked fine for me on ArcGIS9.3 and Python 2.5.

Update:
Running the script from the command line produced an executable oddly enough. Running it from Wing IDE does not.

Comment: Do you execute setup.py in command line (command: python setup.py py2exe) ? What output do you get in shell. Where py2exe says she is locating the files ?

Comment: The code you wrote can not work. It is `distutils` no `disutils`.

Comment: Sorry about that, error when typing my code in here. It is correct in the script.

Comment: When running the script in the command line, it looks for those files in the right directory and I get no errors. I was actually able to create an executable this way, but the executable crashes immediately when I open it.